# How to avoid name hiding warning under Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-warnings, overloading

I have a base class:

```
#define OUT
#define NO_VTABLE __declspec(novtable)

class NO_VTABLE Foo
{
public:

    virtual bool TestSomething() const = 0;

    virtual bool TestSomething(OUT unsigned int& extendedInfo) const {
        UNUSED(extendedInfo);
        return TestSomething();
    }
};
```

And a derived class:

```
class NO_VTABLE Bar : public Foo
{
public:

    virtual bool TestSomething() const {
        // Do the test, return the result...
    }
};
```

Under GCC, the program compiles cleanly with `-Wall -Woverloaded-virtual`. Under Visual Studio, I get a dirty compile. `TestSomething` from above is `Available` shown below.

```
1> ...\derived.h(78) : warning C4266: 'bool DeviceState::Available(unsigned int &) const' :
    no override available for virtual member function from base 'DeviceState'; function is hidden
1>     ...\base.h(794) : see declaration of 'DeviceState::Available'
1>     ...\base.h(787) : see declaration of 'DeviceState'
```

Removing `NO_VTABLE` makes no difference. The warning persists.

All the `TestSomething` are public *and* virtual in both the base and derived classes, so its not clear to me what is hidden from the caller.

I'm working through testing under Visual Studio, and I've encountered it on both Visual Studio 2005, 2008 and 2010. I still have other VS's to test, but at this point, I know its not a one-off.

I prefer not to turn off the warning because the file `base.h` is large with lots of classes, and it might encounter other problems in the future.

What does Visual Studio claim is hidden from the caller? What is the source of the warning under Visual Studio, and how do I clear it?

Comment: As a workaround you could push and pop the warning around the lines causing problems - these are very old compilers after all.

Comment: @Rostislav - Thanks. what does the compiler version have to do with it? As far as I know, both are C++03, which meets the project's requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If you look up error C4266 you'll find that it says `A derived class did not override all overloads of a virtual function.`  So for this compiler you'll need to override all of the overloads for the `unsigned int &` variant to be visible.

I haven't looked up in the language spec to see if this is conforming or not.

Comment: Thanks. The point of confusion for me is Microsoft claiming its hidden. How/why is it hidden?

Comment: @jww Because `Testsomething()` is overriden in Bar but `TestSomething(unsigned int &)` is not.  Having one overload overriden in a class hides all the other overloads in base classes for non-virtual functions and Microsoft has applied that to virtual functions as well.  It might also be to point out that in some parts of the hierarchy (`Bar`) the overload won't be visible at all and require some extra casting to get to it.

Comment: It _is_ hidden. Whether you should care about that or not isn't clear. We know nothing of your use case or of what your most-derived classes will look like.